# Тонкости русского языка

Tags: синонимы

Каким прилагательным можно дополнить слово "горчица", заменив не очень литературное — "ядреная".

Comment: Вполне литературное: ядрёная (от ядра) — быстрая, подвижная, живая.

Comment: Согласен, ядреная - слово вполне литературное, вы с чем-то спутали. Но если надо заменить, то варианты есть, не буду повторять ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Горчица может быть *жгучая*, *острая*, *свежая*.

Comment: Жгучая и острая - скорее, аджика. А "свежая" - не раскрывает сущность.

Answer (score 2):

Крепкая, злая, забористая.

Ядрёная - разговорное слово, но очень выразительное,образное, основное значение "крепкая". Это нейтральное литературное слово. Мне нравится эпитет "злая", а "забористая" - тоже разговорное народное, моя бабушка так говорила, мне нравится.

Answer (score 2):

Русская горчица самая жгучая, самая горячая. Острая, обжигающая.

Ароматно-жгучая, Злая, словно Львица...Кто ответит детки мне - Это что? ...
(Горчица). (Ступников В.)